# can't retrieve data from async call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I am using ngx-translate service for translations in my angular app. I would like to create method that would accept path to string which needs to be returned. My method looks like this:

```
public translateString(parameter: string): string {
    let message = "";
    this.translate.get(parameter).subscribe((response) => {
        message = response;
    });
    return message;
}
```

But it always returns empty string, I think the problem is the subscribe call so return message gets executed before message = response. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The data is not synchronously available. You'll need to return the observable, and then the caller can subscribe to do what they need to do once the message is available.

```
public translateString(parameter: string): Observable<String> {
    return this.translate.get(parameter);
}

// and then used like this:
SomeService.translateString('hello world')
    .subscribe(message => {
        console.log(message);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

use `instant`

It not require any observables.

```
this.message =   this.translate.instant('Language')
```

Comment: this way it return keys instead of value :/

Comment: You already tried it? In my case I'm sending key as mentioned above and getting value of it.

Comment: yes, I have translations in en.json file...when I call this.translate.instant("key inside of en.json") it returns the key instead of value.

Comment: could you show en.json how you structure and what `parameter` are you sending.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return your message inside subscribe.Like this:

```
public translateString(parameter: string): string {
    let message = "";
    this.translate.get(parameter).subscribe((response) => {
        message = response;
        return message;
    });
}
```

Comment: The outer function (translateString) is not returning anything at all, so this code will effectively do nothing.

Comment: @NicholasTower It is returning string,see the first line.

Comment: Are you talking about the type declaration? Yes, it *claims* to be returning a string. But there's no actual return statement.

Comment: What do you mean? Won't it return message ??

Comment: I'm not talking about the inner function, i'm talking about the outer function. There is no return statement in translateString. If someone were to call `SomeSevice.translateString('test')`, it will return undefined.

Comment: I've created a JS fiddle showing what i mean: https://jsfiddle.net/ref3buzx/3/ . Notice that the console will log out 'undefined';